# SFINAE std::isfinite and similar functions using std::is_arithmetic

Tags: c++, c++11, clang++, libc++

I just ran into a compilation failure when porting some code from VS2013 to GGC 4.9 and Clang 3.5 ( using libc++ ). The gist of the code is

```
#include <cmath>

struct Foo
{
    operator double() const { return( 101.0 ); } // Implicit conversion to double
};

int main( int, char** )
{
    Foo foo;

    std::exp( foo );      // Compiles
    std::isfinite( foo ); // Does not

    return( 0 );
}
```

I believe the `isfinite` call does not compile because the `isfinite` funtion in cmath has return type declared as:

```
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<_A1>::value, bool>::type
```

and because `Foo` is not `is_arithmetic`, `isfinite` gets removed from the overload set. The same is true of friends of `isfinite` like `isnan`. So my question is whether this is expected.

Does the standard require that arguments to functions like `isfinite` as actually directly `double` or `float` as opposed to being implicitly convertible to them?

Also I'm a bit unsure why is `std::is_arithmetic` not `std::is_floating_point`, doesn't `is_arithmetic` imply `isfinite` on integers?

As an extra question what is the best way of specifying a constraint like *is_convertible_to_floating_point*?

Comment: Since C++11 [`std::exp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/exp) also accepts integral types as well, not only floating point types.

Comment: And to solve your problem, you can easily add a specialization of [`std::is_arithmetic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic) for your class.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No you can't. Specializing a standard library type trait (except `std::common_type`) is UB.

Comment: The standard says that there should be three overloaded signatures taking `float`, `double` and `long double` respectively. I'd file a bug.

Answer (score 5):

§26.8 [c.math]/p10-11:

> The classification/comparison functions behave the same as the C
>   macros with the corresponding names defined in 7.12.3, Classification
>   macros, and 7.12.14, Comparison macros in the C Standard. Each
>   function is overloaded for the three floating-point types, as follows:
>
> ```
> // other functions omitted
> bool isfinite(float x);
>
> bool isfinite(double x);
>
> bool isfinite(long double x);
> ```
>
> Moreover, there shall be additional overloads sufficient to ensure:
>
> 1. If any arithmetic argument corresponding to a double parameter has type `long double`, then all arithmetic arguments corresponding to
>      `double` parameters are effectively cast to `long double`.
> 2. Otherwise, if any arithmetic argument corresponding to a `double` parameter has type `double` or an integer type, then all arithmetic
>      arguments corresponding to `double` parameters are effectively cast to
>      `double`.
> 3. Otherwise, all arithmetic arguments corresponding to `double` parameters have type `float`.

I'd file a bug against libc++.

Comment: Just to note this applies to the GCC libstdc++ as well

Comment: @goneskiing It works fine when I [tested against libstdc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb0d355028099712).

Comment: I'm using GCC 4.9.1 ( normal Ubuntu Package ) on Ubuntu 14.10 with command line "gcc foo.cpp" gives "error: no matching function for call to ‘isfinite(Foo&)’ ...". Are you using 4.8, looking at the cmath header it seems pretty different.

Comment: Ah "gcc -std=c++11 foo.cpp" does work. Seem odd they don't def out the enable_if, that is assuming no "-std" options means c++98, if you just do "gcc foo.cpp"

Comment: I just discovered bug http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18218 against libc++ which talks about exactly this problem, so should get fixed at some point

Comment: Actually Marshall Clow wrote this http://marshall.calepin.co/doing-a-good-job-with-ltcmathgt.html on this and many related issues in implementing cmath

Comment: Yeah, it's an icky problem, and I *still* don't have a good solution.